# How do I format dates from Mongoose in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, date, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to change the format of the dates I'm getting from my Mongo database. Currently they look like this:

```
Fri Sep 16 2011 19:05:17 GMT+0900 (JST)
```

I've tried calling `.toString('yyyy-MM-dd')` on them but nothing changes. I don't know if they're `Date` objects or just raw strings.

I've tried checking the Mongoose manual and googling a bunch, but not found anything yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass you date string to new Date("Fri Sep 16 2011 19:05:17 GMT+0900").getTime() then perform your regular date methods.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have to create a Date object first:

```
var date = new Date(dateStr);  // dateStr you get from mongodb

var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth()+1;
// ...
```

Comment: will ```var m = date.getMonth() + 1;``` work for december(12), since plus 1 makes 13, which is not a true month?

Comment: @Sahin JS months are 0-index based meaning that months look like this: Jan=0 ... Dez=11

Answer (score 29):

A modern way to do this is to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/), both usable in node and in the browser, super useful and simple to use. For the current problem I solved it like this in node after following all the docs requirements :

```
var moment = require('moment');
var fomatted_date = moment(photo.date_published).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

with `photo.date_published` directly coming from mongoose.

Comment: `YYYY-DD-MM` should be `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: The only problem I faced with this approach is the time is converted to local timezone and I see a different in the rendered date because of this. I'm looking a substr() like approach and stumbled upon this post.

Answer (score 13):

what about defining your schema like:

```
var someSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    created: Date
});
```

s.t. the date is stored as a `Date` object in your mongoDB. As a result, when you read it back you'll have a proper `Date` object on which you can work with the available methods.

Comment: That sounds like crazy-genius. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: how do you validate that? for example, being born in the last century... (?)

Answer (score 4):

Just Simply Add

`date: { type: String, default: Date }`

Output will be: {  "date": "Sat Nov 28 2020 22:57:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" }

Answer (score 0):

created_at:{
type:Date,
default:Date.now
}
add this simple line for current date and time

**output:-----
Fri Jul 02 2021 10:45:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is, in the Schema, I define dates with a *Date* type:

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true  // or false, depending upon needs (plus other options, as needed)
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true  // or false, depending upon needs (plus other options, as needed)
    },
    whateverDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true  // or false, depending upon needs (plus other options, as needed)
    }
});
```

Then I define an instance method for the mongoose schema:

```
// Returns a date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format
exampleSchema.methods.formatDate = function(datePropery) {
    const newDate = new Date(this[dateProperty]);
    let formattedDate = `${ newDate.getFullYear() }-`;
        formattedDate += `${ `0${ newDate.getMonth() + 1 }`.slice(-2) }-`;  // for double digit month
        formattedDate += `${ `0${ newDate.getDate() }`.slice(-2) }`;        // for double digit day
    return formattedDate;
}
```

And, define the mongoose model:

```
const Example = new mongoose.model('Example', exampleSchema);
```

Later, after I've selected a particular instance (for me this is generally within an *async* function), e.g.

```
const item = await Example.findOne({searchFor: searchTerm});
```

I can get the formatted dates in the following way:

```
item.formatDate('startDate');     // for startDate field (see exampleSchema), or
item.formatDate('endDate');       // for endDate field (see exampleSchema), or
item.formatDate('whateverDate');  // for whateverDate field (see exampleSchema).
```

If the item is passed from *Express* to HTML, e.g.:

```
res.render('mypage', {item});
```

it can then be used in HTML (at least for the case of *ejs* view engine) as:

```
<%= item.formatDate('startDate') %>
<%= item.formatDate('endDate') %>
<%= item.formatDate('whateverDate') %>
```

Perhaps this is a bit long-winded, although it works nicely for me.