# Why is mongoose changing date attributes's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Model that has a date attribute, I'm getting it's value from a post request. I have at least two problems:

1. Mongoose is accepting this input as a date : `19124-012-030`
2. When I send only the year Mongoose fills the month and day and changes the year value.

I haven't tried anything yet, I don't have any validation in my schema, I'm relying only on the type proprety (`type: Date`)

**Schema**:

```
const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    date: {
     type: Date
    },
});
```

**Form**:

```
<input id="dat" type="text" name="date" placeholder="date (yyyy-mm-dd)">
```

**Route handler**:

```
app.post("/api/exercise/add", function(req, res, next) {
    User
     .findById(req.body.userId)
     .exec()
     .then(function(user) {
       return Promise.all([user, new Exercise({
         description: req.body.description,
         duration: req.body.duration,
         date: req.body.date, //BUG: must add validations
         user: user
       }).save()]);
     })
     .then(function([user, exercise]) {
        user.exercises.push(exercise);
        return user.save();
     })
     .then(user => res.json({ status: 201, exercises: user.exercises }))
     .catch(err => next(err))
     });
```

(1)The expected output of `19124-012-030` is to raise an error, instead the object gets persisted with : `19124-12-29T23:00:00.000+00:00`
(2)When the input is only `11111` the object is persisted with : `11110-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00`

**Update**
The issue  is on. I have not found anything similar. Nothing is provided in MongoDB's documentation to help understand the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443142/how-do-i-format-dates-from-mongoose-in-node-js

Comment: @tnkh I don't think the problem has anything to do with formatting the date object.