# Javascript json array filter with date

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

JSON response from the server and I need to filter with the date(year) before to show client-side

**example**

```
person = [{ name: String, birth: Date }]



function fltr(name, year){
   return person.filter(res => ( res.name == name && res.birth.getFullYear() === year) )
}

fltr('jon', 1990 );
```

added getFullYear() in condition `res.birth.getFullYear()`  to match with year but not working , Please correct me

Please

Comment: Please share the error you are getting as well as the input and expected output.

Comment: looks like it works just fine to me

Comment: You say you get json from the server -- JSON cannot encode dates, so you have to manually iterate over your person array and change the date strings into javascript date objects. Have you done this already?

Comment: I doubt that a `JSON response` contains `Date object`? It could be a string! See if you are overlooking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would guess your date format is wrong, since the following works pretty well:

```js
const people = [{ name: 'Kaiser Soze', birthDate: '1995/06/20' }];
const filterByNameAndBirthYear = (name, year) => {
  return people.filter(person => person.name === name && new Date(person.birthDate).getFullYear() === year);
}
let result = filterByNameAndBirthYear('Kaiser Soze', 1995);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are using non-standard date formats. Please read [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715259/what-are-valid-date-time-strings-in-javascript). For example, `new Date('1995/06/20')` is not the same as `new Date('1995-06-20')`.

Comment: @str https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: What is the syntax for adding standard Date format in Mongoose Schema?

Comment: @ShibinRagh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443142/how-do-i-format-dates-from-mongoose-in-node-js

Comment: @Dementic What is your point? `1995/06/20` is not a valid date format according to the specification.

Comment: @str anything without a timezone (T) is valid.

Comment: @Dementic That is incorrect. Only the [specified date time string formats](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) are valid.